# VisualVM - how do I connect?

Tags: java, visualvm

This seems like a ridiculous question to ask. A google search for `VisualVM` brings up lots of information, including, supposedly that it's easy to connect to a running `JVM` and monitor.

Well, that's just not the case. I can't figure out how to connect `VisualVM` to my running application to save my life. What am I doing wrong (or maybe more accurately, what am I *not* doing right)?

When I launch my program, a new VM entry for the program appears in the local VMs pane, but when I try to "connect" it just sits there "spinning". Finally, when my program exits (or I stop it), the connect attempt fails.

Is there some sort of VM arguments or some agent that needs to be defined when I launch my application? Do I need to compile it in a specific way? Do I need some other "actor" involved?

I found one [site](http://www.hsufengko.com/blog/monitor-java-application-with-visualvm) that included some info I have not seen anywhere else, but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE**:

On a slightly different but related topic, I ran the java `hprof` profiler on my program, which produces a binary or text file with info collected. Supposedly `VisualVM` can open this information and allow for visual browsing of what was collected. It opens the file and reports at least some correct info, such as the size and location of the file, but it behaves as though there is no data to show.

Comment: Do you use the exact same JDK to run VisualVM and your application? It should be enough to right click on the application and then choose "Open"

Comment: I don't think I was at first, but upon reading your comment, made attempts to ensure that the running JVM and VisualVM were both using the same JDK version. It still won't connect.

Comment: How exactly are you starting your application?

Comment: I'm launching it from within eclipse.

Comment: What is the significance of the program and VisualVM using the exact same JDK?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to run VisualVM from within the IDE, but if both your running application and the VisualVM process are on the same box/server, VisualVM should be able to "see" the other application as long as it's running.

Try these steps:

- Download the latest VisualVM package from here: https://visualvm.github.io/download.html
- Install it.  See the `First Steps` and `Possible Problems` section on that webpage if you run into any issues.
- Run your application within Eclipse.
- Switch to VisualVM.  You should now see a new entry under the `Local` section in the Applications window.
- Double click on that, and you'll be able to monitor your application.